# jdbc sql server error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I'm using eclipse, trying to connect to a sql server db. I have the jars in my build path. I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
>   driver    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:325)
>     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:353)

Here is my code:

```
  import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class connect
    {
       public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
                String db_userid,
                String db_password)
       {
          try {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string,
                      db_userid, db_password);
             System.out.println("connected");
             Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
             String queryString = "select * from sysobjects where type='u'";
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
             while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
             }
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          connect connServer = new connect();
          connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ssdd.ffd.aduat.fdd.com:5150", "rre",
                   "wer");
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think u r trying to use the JTDS URL with the MS SQL driver. What is the jar u have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string is wrong. It should be just "`jdbc:sqlserver://....`". Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).